# Trying to understand the fields of std::_Sp_counted_base in gcc's bits/shared_ptr_base.h header file

Tags: c++, g++

I'm reading the g++ implementations of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr`, and **I cannot figure out why `sizeof(std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::__default_lock_policy>)` is not 8**.

In bits/shared_ptr_base.h:

1. `std::shared_ptr<_Tp>` derives from `std::__shared_ptr<_Tp>`.
2. `std::__shared_ptr<_Tp>` has an `element_type*` and a `__shared_count<_Lp>`. `_Lp` represents a lock policy.
3. `std::__shared_count<_Lp>` is a wrapper of `std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>*`.

Then:

1. `std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>` derives from `std::_Mutex_base<_Lp>`. Since `std::_Mutex_base<_Lp>` is an empty base class when `_Lp` is not `__gnu_cxx::_S_mutex` and the default value is `__gnu_cxx::_S_atomic`, it will not contribute to `std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>`'s size in my case.
2. There are only 2 fields in `std::_Sp_counted_base<_Lp>`'s definition: `_M_use_count` and `_M_weak_count`. They are both `_Atomic_word`, which is a type alias of `int`.
3. So `std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::__default_lock_policy>` should be 8 bytes?

https://godbolt.org/z/8dK7G1ar1

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <iomanip>

template <typename... Ts>
void println(Ts &&... xs) {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    ((std::cout << xs << " "), ...);
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main() {
    static_assert(__gnu_cxx::__default_lock_policy == __gnu_cxx::_S_atomic);
    println("_Sp_counted_base   ", sizeof(std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::__default_lock_policy>));
    println("_Atomic_word       ", sizeof(_Atomic_word));
    println("_Mutex_base        ", sizeof(std::_Mutex_base<__gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>));
    println("_Sp_counted_base<a>", sizeof(std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::_S_atomic>));
    println("_Sp_counted_base<m>", sizeof(std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::_S_mutex>));
    println("_Sp_counted_base<s>", sizeof(std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::_S_single>));
}
```

I compiled the code with gcc 13.2. `sizeof(std::_Sp_counted_base<__gnu_cxx::__default_lock_policy>))` is 16 in 64-bit mode and 12 in 32-bit mode. Is there a hidden `long` or pointer field that I missed? The source I'm reading is g++ 14.0.1, but even when I change the compiler version, the result stays the same.

Comment: This is implementation detail and is not set by the standard. In any case the shared pointer control block consists of a pointer to a deleter, strong reference counter, week reference counter. You missed a deleter.

Comment: @273K Thanks for the reply. I know the issue is implemented-related and is not specified by the standard. I only want to know why the code behaves like this. I checked the code twice, and your reply helps a lot. `std::_Sp_counted_base` indeed has a virtual function for getting the deleter: `virtual void* _M_get_deleter(const std::type_info&) noexcept = 0;`. This means `std::_Sp_counted_base` has an extra virtual pointer besides the 2 atomic fields.